# Matching Requirements in Multiple Records of a Table in Excel

Tags: excel

I've searched for this issue for quite some time and I now had to create an account to ask. It feels like such a generic question and I'm not sure how to tag it.

I need to create a table in excel that has a list of customers in column A and then 10 columns in B through K with 10 uniform customer labeling requirements (i.e. if a customer needs the requirement in column C, they get a mark in column C on their row). I want an easy way to see what customers have the same requirements. My first thought is this:

```
Customer      Requirement B      Requirement C      Requirement D      Concatenated
John's Tools       B                  C                                  BC
Kate's Cats        B                                     D               BD
Tim's Toys                            C                                  C
Jack's Gym         B                  C                  D               BCD
Carl's Cars        B                  C                                  BC
```

I'm thinking if I just sort on the concatenated column, it will give me what I'm looking for, but maybe the community here has a different thought. Here's what I think it would look like sorted:

```
Customer      Requirement B      Requirement C      Requirement D      Concatenated
Carl's Cars        B                  C                                  BC
John's Tools       B                  C                                  BC
Jack's Gym         B                  C                  D               BCD
Kate's Cats        B                                     D               BD
Tim's Toys                            C                                  C
```

If anyone thinks there is a better way to utilize this table (or if it's the wrong format to begin with) to see the matching requirements, I would love to see it.

BONUS CHALLENGE: I'm also looking for a way to see if customers are "mostly similar," as my boss puts it, but I'm just leaving this out there. I think the sorting method works okay, but it doesn't help if two customers are extremely similar (6 out of 7 requirements) but have a different beginning requirement (i.e. B and C would be sorted far away from each other because of how many customers are in the table).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of concatenating the fields is not a bad option and will work.  However, have you considered using TABLES and even PIVOT tables.

If you enable tables (select your data, then click Home/Format as Table) then you could easily apply a filter on all clients that have a "B" in the requirement "B" column, and in "C" etc.  The filter in the TABLE works on the "AND" condition, so if you select all the filters, then the end result will be only the people that actually need to complete all the requirements.  Selecting a "blank" in one of the filters will only show the people that don't need that requirement.

You could also achieve something very similiar with a pivot table, but that will be slightly more processing intensive.

Regarding your bonus question, you could assign a weight to each requirement and sum the weights up.  So, assume the definition of "similiar" is AB is the same as AC, but ABC is different, then you could assign a value of say 100 to A, 50 to B, 50 to C, then by summing up the requirements, you will get 150 for both AB and AC, and 200 for ABC.  Couple of ways to achieve that, but you will require input from your boss to determine what is defined as "like each other" and it will most likely require some tweaking.